# Django Filters with Rest Framework Authentication message filtering strategy/issue in a Chat application

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter, ed

I have a Django DRF backend, with token user authentication implemented. The application itself is a chat which consists of  public Lobbies and private Threads (Threads between particular users). Currently my models file includes Message model which has foreign key relation to the Lobby and Thread models and keeps one of those fields as Null, to determine wheter the particular message concerns private Thread or public Lobby.

So far I have been focusing on developing the public Lobbies, where the user was querying the messages based on the Lobby he was currently in.

After i finished the development of Lobbies and enabled the authentication, the frontend stopped filtering the messages by the Lobby title and just kept simply returning me all messages relevant to the current authenticated user - obviously disregarding any disctinction between Lobbies the messages are related to. After inspecting the actual API, i found out that when i enable authentication, the Filtering option completely disappears from the page.

```
how can I combat this issue?
```

**EDIT**: i updated the post with some code
I would rather keep one Message model rather creating separate Message models for Lobby and Thread.

here are my models :

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user1")
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user2")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False) 
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"user1: {self.user1} user2: {self.user2}"

class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255, default="", blank=False, null=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

    lobby = models.ForeignKey(Lobby, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="messages", blank=True, null=True )
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="messages", blank=True,
    null=True )

class Lobby(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=90, blank=False, null=False)
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='lobby.jpg')
```

here are the serializers :

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user1 = serializers.CharField(source="user1.username")
    user1thumb = serializers.CharField(source="user1.accountimage.image.url")
    user2 = serializers.CharField(source="user2.username")
    user2thumb = serializers.CharField(source="user2.accountimage.image.url")
    class Meta:
        model= Thread
        fields = ["user1", "user2", "user1thumb", "user2thumb"]


class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    thumb = serializers.CharField(source='user.accountimage.image.url')
    class Meta:
        model= Message
        fields=['id','content', 'username', 'thumb']

class LobbySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Lobby
        fields="__all__"
        depth=2
```

and finally the views :

```
class ThreadView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Thread.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.request.user)
        return Thread.objects.filter(Q(user1= self.request.user) | Q(user2=self.request.user))


class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    filter_fields=('lobby__title',)



class LobbyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lobby.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LobbySerializer
```

in my settings.py i enabled the Authentication globally:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ], 
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    )
}
```

Comment: can you re-ask the question with more code and less text plz?

Comment: @engin_ipek  since there was no actual code, i included the code for the project. If the subject of matter is not clear enought please let me now, so i can try to format the text more briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:
Your problem has nothing to do with authorization. You are adding a

> "REST_FRAMEWORK"

setting block, but not specifiying a filter backend to use

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ], 
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',]

}
```

and replace

> filter_fields = ('lobby__title',)

with:

```
filterset_fields = ['lobby__title',]
```

P.S: you need to `pip install django-filter` if you haven't

I hope this helps!

Comment: this seems not to be the case, there is something different going on. I did exactly like you said, and all that happened is that i have another field in my data.  This is strange behaviour to consider, since when i commented out the whole authorization thing in the settings.py , everything seems fine and i have the "filter" icon in my API [link](https://imgur.com/a/w82LRRn)   but as soon as i add authentication, and log in as a user, the filter icon dissappears (??) [link](https://imgur.com/a/s3fEbQR)  i dont understand this behaviour, maybe i should consider rewriting the views

Comment: Thank's so much ! This has solved the issue ! Thanks again ! btw what's your opinion on this private Thread vs public Lobby serialization/auth issue ? couse there is one model Messsage for both. It should not be restricted to a particular user as far as main Lobbies are concerned, but i don't want other users to be able to fetch private messages they don't own. Might this couse me some problems, or should i not worry so much about this?